# updating json using javascript for hierarchy objects

Tags: javascript, tree, iteration

A quick question, I want to update the json using javascript without iteration.

**Example**:

```
{ "parent":{
  "id":"1",
  "status":"Bad",
  "children":[
     {
        "id":"2",
        "status":"Good",
        "children":[
           {
              "id":"3",
              "status":"Bad",
              "children":[

              ]
           },
           {
              "id":"4",
               "status":"Bad",
              "children":[

              ]
           }
        ]
     },
     {
        "id":"4",
        "status":"Bad",
        "children":[
           {
              "id":"3",
              "status":"Bad",
              "children":[

              ]
           },
           {
              "id":"4",
               "status":"Bad",
              "children":[

              ]
           }
        ]
     }
  ]
}}
```

In this tree structure, id will be common for many objects. If I want to update the status for all the id's of "3", Currently am going on with the iteration to find the corresponding ids and am updating the status. It is very time consuming, Is there a way that i can update the status using ids without iteration.

I found a js called 'pinch' but it is of no use, it is internally doing the same iteration. So Is there a way where i can update the status without doing a iteration.

I welcome the best traversal idea also.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible without some form of iteration.

Comment: thanks for your reply kevin Bowersox, Is there any best traversal idea to update the json as I expect.

Comment: user2864740, I got your idea, you want me to convert that like map then you want me to traverse, Is there any specific example. Please do let me know.

Comment: It sounds like you're not taking advantage of a possible constraint on your data. If all nodes with the same id will always have the same status, then you really should just restructure your json object so that you have an object mapping ids to statuses and another object representing the tree of nodes with the statuses removed. This way you can update the status of all nodes with the same id in constant time, while still being able to look up the status of any given node in constant time using indirection.

Comment: james, thanks for ur reply. I have shown an simple example where i just want to update the single param. But in real case i want to update multiple params like status, colour etc., Could u pls give me an simple example for what you asked me to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can store you objects like this:

```
objs = [
{"id":"1","status":"Bad",children:[]},
{"id":"2","status":"Good",children:[]},
{"id":"3","status":"Bad",children:[]},
{"id":"4","status":"Bad",children:[]}]

objs[0].children=[objs[1],objs[2]]

objs.map(function(t){t.status="Updated"})
```

In this way JS handle params by links and you can do any with the list - the changes will appear also in json obj.

Comment: thanks kirill, as of now mapping is not my choice... i did the best traversal iteration using depth search...

Answer (score 0):

You can do with recursive functions like this:

```
function getChildren(children, map, current){

if( current != null && map.indexOf(current) != 0 ) 
    return children || [];

if(current== null)
    current = "";

if(!children){
    //todo : here you can update "children" of the node you want, via ajax etc..
}

if(map == current)
    return children;

var fchildren = []; 
for(var i= 0; i < children.length; i++ ){
    var n = children[i];
    var node = {
        "id" : n.id,
        "name" : n.name,
        "children": getChildren(n.children, map, current+(current?"-":"")+n.id )
    };
    fchildren.push(node);
}
return fchildren;
```

};

for example you want to update children of node with id : 3
your path is (in your example): "1-2-3"

Usage :

```
TreeData = {
id: 0,
status:"good",
children : getChildren(TreeData, "1-2-3")};
```